# Remove border off of an input type image button?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<form>
    <input type="image" value=" " class="btnimage" />
</form>
...
```

CSS:

```
.btnimage {
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px;
    background:url('C:/Users/John/Desktop/Misc Things for the CoD Ghosts Site/SubmitButton.png');
}
.btnimage:hover {
    background-position: 0 -25px;
    background:url('C:/Users/John/Desktop/Misc Things for the CoD Ghosts Site/SubmitButtononHover.png');
}
```

The above code works, but there's a border that surrounds the button, which I want to go away. So far, I've tried adding `background-border:0;` to both of the classes, and it did not work.

Comment: First, is there a border on your image itself? Also, is this actually working since the url of background is not file:// ??

Comment: Then, if there is no border on your image itself, you have answers.

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns and when i created the images i didn't put an outline/border on them, but when i actually make a border around the button, it shows the outline that i want removed, and a border, so i'll have to check out my images to see if the outline/border is part of the image. if it is, i'll remove it and it should work.

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns well it's not my images...

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns if there is no way to remove it, that's fine, i can live with it, but I'd prefer to have it gone

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a big image - all based on he comments above and below - http://jsfiddle.net/tZd4Q/

Comment: @TimSPQR how's that supposed to help

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns yes i have they do not work either. i'll talk to you guys tomorrow, have to go now.

Comment: If you are not able to include a screen capture of what you want to show within your question, you can still link it to a website like imageshack.com, tinypic.com or imgur.com

Comment: @Milkywayspatterns I'll try to insert it into the question later today.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that your image is not covering the entire button, and so around the edge of your image you can still see some of the underlying button?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
input {
    /* sets border width to 0 and border style to none */ 
    border:0 none;
}
```

or

```
input {
    border: 0px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Button borders use outline in browsers. It is a default.

Comment: Michelle are you sure of that? An outline is a line that is drawn around elements (outside the borders) to make the element "stand out".

Comment: @AlienArrays, i was shy to edit and remove the second part of your answer. Fixing border width to 0px with a style and a color is not removing it completely. You should just suggest 'border:0 none;'

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I've run across this problem multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome

Answer (score 3):

```
background-border is not a css property
```

You can remove a border with css by setting it's width to 0 or it style to none.

To avoid an internet explorer legacy bug, you have to specify a `border-width` or a `border-color` to make `border-style:none` apply. So your best bet if you care about my grandma, it to use `border:0 none;`

```
.btnimage {
    border: 0 none;
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px;
    background:url('C:/Users/John/Desktop/Misc Things for the CoD Ghosts Site/SubmitButton.png');
}
```

---

Since you did not mention when your border is visible, perhaps it an outline visible on your input focus.

If it is your case, add :

```
.btnimage:focus {
    outline:0
}
```

Comment: If the OP actually needed to specify that there is no border, they would use border: 0; NOT border: 0 none; Border: 0; will simply remove the borders entirely. There is no need to specify that there is no style to it

Comment: Michelle, see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598585/why-an-image-still-has-a-border-in-ie-even-with-border-set-to-none#11601184. I won't take more time to provide you with a better link for ie haslayout form field border bug. But you can give it a try. Bonne soirée.

Comment: if you guys want, i'll send you a screenshot of the problem through e-mail because i don't think anyone is understanding my question

Comment: @xNirdx If none of us understood your question, perhaps it's your question itself that needs a review.

Answer (score 2):

```
input {
  border:0 none !important;
  outline:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that you define an input type="image", but not provide a source, so this border is like a broken image, because when you set the type as image the input expects an src attribute as well.

In my opinion you have 2 solutions:

1st: set the "src" property of the input, in the HTML code, and if you want to change the hover image, you can do this through javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<form>
    <input type="image" src="your_image_url" class="btnimage" />
</form>
...
```

2nd: change it to input type "button", or a link " ", than remove border and background in the CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<form>
    <input type="button" class="btnimage" />
</form>
...
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Bpv34/

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
border:none none;
```

Yes working

Answer (score 0):

To remove the border, write the following line in your CSS wherever the border appears:

```
outline: 0;
```

Comment: Oups, Michelle, this is to remove the OUTLINE, not the border. An outline is a line that is drawn around elements (outside the borders) to make the element "stand out".

Comment: The BUTTON element as well as the INPUT element uses OUTLINE as a default, NOT border.

Answer (score 0):

try the prefixes too

```
input {

    border:0 none;
    -moz-border:0 none;   
    -webkit-border:0 none;  
     outline: 0;  //add this too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input {
  border:0 none !important;
}
```

by writing important it will definately work.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use src attribute to define image url.

2) Use custom button with div - something like:

```
<div class="btnimage" onclick="blablabla()">Button</div>
```

It can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked for me. All attempts with "border" did not work:

```
input { outline: 0 !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just having trouble with this too.
First off, you may as well set the src equal to an image you want to use if you are using the input type of 'image'

Here is mine: `<input type='image' src='img/share.png' alt='Share'>`

Then make adjustments in your css:

```
#fbshare input[type="image"] {outline:none;}
#fbshare input[type="image"]:active {outline:none;}
```

This solved my problem in Chrome, and I presume it should solve yours too. If it is still a problem nearly 2 years later. (I mostly posted this for others who find this page in a google search)

This page helped me come to the above conclusion.
http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/remove-border-after-clicking-button/33948

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as the OP - specifically for an image input. It certainly seems to be because of the browser interpreting it as a "broken image" if no `src` attribute is set.

So this works as a solution, by setting the attribute to a single transparent pixel, the image input non-border non-outline "border" goes away:

```
<input type="image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="btnimage">
```

No CSS needed (or seems to work.)