# Border on HTML button

Tags: html, button

How do you remove the border around an HTML button (i.e. as a static button and when clicked)?

e.g.

```
<input type="button" alt="Go" id="search" onclick="submit();">
```

with CSS:

```
#search {
    background: url('http://www.morguefile.com/img/searchIcon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    width: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F4u75/

Comment: Like this: `border:none;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove border off of an input type image button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058017/remove-border-off-of-an-input-type-image-button)

Comment: Not a dupe of that—this does not have an image button. It probably should, but it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
border: 0;
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/F4u75/1/

Answer (score 0):

With the border property.

```
border: 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F4u75/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add:

```
border: none;
```

to the CSS.